# How to avoid page break after table?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, r, xtable

I have a small LaTeX table (tabular) created in R with the xtable package and I would like to place a figure underneath the table on the SAME page. I have tried various things (using packages float, needspace, etoolbox, etc etc), but I don't seem to get it completely right... It also doesn't work if I just put random text after the table.

How can I force to not have a page break after the table?

My code looks like this (omitting the packages) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\include{small_table}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{piechart.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Because I make the small table file from R, I want to avoid altering that file. However it looks something like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
     bla & bla 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! How about: after your `\end{tabular}` putting a blank line and then `\includegraphics{piechart.eps}`?

Comment: Because I am making lots of tables in R I would like a solution where I don't need to edit the small table file... So I would like a solution where the first code part is altered to achieve the result.
I edited my questions now. Hope it makes sense...

Comment: `\include` _always forces a page break, use `\input`

Comment: then you need `\begin{figure}[htp]` to allow the figure to be in the page rather than float to top

Answer (score 5):

`\include` _always forces a page break, use `\input`, and then allow the figure to be on the same page by including `h` in its option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\input{small_table}

\begin{figure}[htp]
   \includegraphics{piechart.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Works perfect! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

One could also extent David's solution by adding a `\nopagebreak` between the table and the figure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\input{small_table}
\nopagebreak
\begin{figure}[htp]
   \includegraphics{piechart.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can also specify an optional value between `0` and `4` to `\nopagebreak`. The higher the value, the less likely is a pagebreak at that position.